# SetBackGroundColor doesn't work in CardView

Tags: android, android-studio, cardview

**Hello everyone, please help me out!!!**

I want to change CardView color in RecyclerView.

[Here is the result, but I want to change different color for each CardView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyE9E.png)

*Here is my code in onBindViewHolder*

```
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardViewHolder cardViewHolder, int i){
        Course course = getListCourses().get(i);
        cardViewHolder.tvCourseTitle.setText(course.getCourseTitle());
        cardViewHolder.tvCourseShortDescription.setText(course.getCourseShortDescription());
        cardViewHolder.imgCourse.setImageResource(course.getCourseImage());
        cardViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(course.getCourseColor()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return getListCourses().size();
    }
    public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ImageView imgCourse;
        private TextView tvCourseTitle, tvCourseShortDescription;
        private CardView cardView, cardViewContainer;


        public CardViewHolder (@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            imgCourse = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_item_course);
            tvCourseTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_title);
            tvCourseShortDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_short_description);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView_background);
            cardViewContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        }
    }
}
```

*Here is the code in Java.lang*

```
    String courseTitle, courseShortDescription, courseColor;
    int courseImage;

    public Course(String title, String description, int image, String color){
        this.courseTitle = title;
        this.courseShortDescription = description;
        this.courseImage = image;
        this.courseColor = color;
    }

    public String getCourseTitle() {
        return courseTitle;
    }

    public void setCourseTitle(String courseTitle) {
        this.courseTitle = courseTitle;
    }

    public String getCourseShortDescription() {
        return courseShortDescription;
    }

    public void setCourseShortDescription(String courseShortDescription) {
        this.courseShortDescription = courseShortDescription;
    }

    public String getCourseColor() {
        return courseColor;
    }

    public void setCourseColor(String courseColor) {
        this.courseColor = courseColor;
    }

    public int getCourseImage() {
        return courseImage;
    }

    public void setCourseImage(int courseImage) {
        this.courseImage = courseImage;
    }
}
```

**Note when I use method cardViewHolder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(course.getCourseColor())); , app get ruinn**

Answer (score 1):

Different color for each card view , you can set in your `onBindViewHolder()` using condition like this

```
   if (course.getCourseTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Hello Android")){
        cardViewHolder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.teal_200);
    } else if (course.getCourseTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Hello Python")){
        cardViewHolder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.teal_700);
    }else if (course.getCourseTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Android Basic")){
        cardViewHolder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.design_default_color_error);
    }
```